# How to draw mean as a dotted line in boxplot using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I was wondering if it's possible to draw a dotted line that corresponds to the mean value of my data in a box plot.

I know that there is possible to draw shapes with `stat_summary()` like for example drawing a **+** corresponding to the mean with `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, shape="+", size=1, color = "black")` nearest thing is using the `geom="crossbar"` but this is not dotted.

The idea is to get this graphed

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by setting `linetype="dotted"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", fun = "mean", linetype = "dotted", width = .75)
```

[image]

Comment: really usedfull as always @stefan